# Ambiguous import 'google/protobuf/wrappers.proto' on Idea Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, protocol-buffers

I am getting the compile error on Idea IntelliJ with protobuf project while importing

`import "google/protobuf/wrappers.proto";`

maven compile is success. I can run the project with issue. But, IntelliJ is unable to compile.

- Can see /target/protoc-dependencies/b0d55b38f77ee508fc0556e64670ec58/google/protobuf/wrapper.proto

Pls help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCpAP.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uaIBP.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEEXy.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hjhel.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjOjj.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nL9kQ.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bk2XH.png)

IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-232.8660.185, built on July 26, 2023

Runtime version: 17.0.7+7-b1000.6 aarch64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o

```
syntax = "proto3";

package package2;

import "common/address.proto";
import "google/protobuf/wrappers.proto";

option java_package = "org.example.package2";
option java_multiple_files = true;

message Student {
  string name = 1;
  optional int32 id = 2;
  common.Address address = 3;
  google.protobuf.Int32Value age = 4;
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>protobuff-project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>21</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>21</maven.compiler.target>
        <grpc.version>1.62.2</grpc.version>
        <tomcat.annotations.version>6.0.53</tomcat.annotations.version>
        <jackson.version>2.16.1</jackson.version>
        <junit.version>5.10.2</junit.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <protoc.version>3.25.3</protoc.version>
        <logback.version>1.4.12</logback.version>
        <os.maven.plugin.version>1.7.1</os.maven.plugin.version>
        <protobuf.maven.plugin.version>0.6.1</protobuf.maven.plugin.version>
        <surefire.version>3.2.3</surefire.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- grpc / proto related dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-netty-shaded</artifactId>
            <version>${grpc.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-protobuf</artifactId>
            <version>${grpc.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-stub</artifactId>
            <version>${grpc.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
            <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.25.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- necessary for Java 9+ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>annotations-api</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat.annotations.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.30</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Jackson lib for a performance test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <extensions>
            <extension>
                <groupId>kr.motd.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>os-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${os.maven.plugin.version}</version>
            </extension>
        </extensions>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>21</source>
                    <target>21</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${surefire.version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.xolstice.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>protobuf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${protobuf.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <protocArtifact>com.google.protobuf:protoc:${protoc.version}:exe:${os.detected.classifier}</protocArtifact>
                    <pluginId>grpc-java</pluginId>
                    <pluginArtifact>io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:${grpc.version}:exe:${os.detected.classifier}</pluginArtifact>
                    <protoSourceRoot>
                        ${basedir}/src/main/proto/
                    </protoSourceRoot>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>compile-custom</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Unfamiliar with IntelliJ. You likely don't need to manually add Google's Well-Known Types (WKTs) including `timestamp.proto` and `wrappers.proto` to your project as these are generally accessible (through location) once `protoc` is accessible. The error message is unclear but it suggests that the IDE Is unable to determine a unique reference for the import (i.e. there are multiple) suggesting you've added the WKTs multiple times.

Comment: Thanks @DazWilkin
I got the point. But, I have not added any WKTs explicitly. 
Everything is coming from pom.xml. Ref: description above.

How can avoid multiple WKTs to avoid ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't import **protobuf-java** in the pom

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
  <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
  <version>3.25.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks @Clare. 
But, It does not resolve the issue. I am still getting compile error on the intelliJ.